# How to use "MULT" when no number next to it?

Tags: math, lisp

I am new to LISP programming and was seeing if anyone could help me with this basic problem.

```
(MULT (ADD 3 (EXP 3 2)) (DIV 36 (MULT (SUB 6 4) 6)))
```

I am having trouble what `MULT` means when there are no numbers next to it.

Comment: What dialect of Lisp is this?

Comment: It multiplies the result of the expressions in its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to a function can be any expression, they don't have to be literals. So this means to evaluate the two expressions

```
(ADD 3 (EXP 3 2))
```

and

```
(DIV 36 (MULT (SUB 6 4) 6))
```

and then multiply their values.

This continues recursively, so

```
(ADD 3 (EXP 3 2))
```

means to calculate `(EXP 3 2)` and add 3 to that.

If you're familiar with more traditional languages like C, this is equivalent to

```
mult(add(3, exp(3, 2)), div(36, mult(sub(6, 4) 6)))
```

Answer (score 2):

MULT is applied to two arguments A and B, underlined here:

```
(MULT (ADD 3 (EXP 3 2)) (DIV 36 (MULT (SUB 6 4) 6)))
      -A--------------- =B=========================
```

The [substitution model of evaluation](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node10.html) says that first <sup>**[1]**</sup> A is evaluated, then B, then their respective result is put in place of their original expression. Let's evaluate A:

```
(ADD 3 (EXP 3 2))
     ^ ---------
```

Here again, there are two arguments. The evaluation is done in order, first 3, which evaluates to itself, then `(EXP 3 2)`, which is 9. So we can rewrite the above as:

```
(ADD 3 9)
```

Now, ADD can be computed, the result is 12. The original expression is equivalent to:

```
(MULT 12 (DIV 36 (MULT (SUB 6 4) 6)))
         =B=========================
```

Likewise, we can evalute B:

```
(DIV 36 (MULT (SUB 6 4) 6))
        ------------------
```

36 is already a literal, and the second term evaluates to 12 (I skipped some steps). The expression is thus equivalent to:

```
(DIV 36 12)
```

Which, once evaluated, yields 3.

The original expression is equivalent to:

```
(MULT 12 3)
```

Which is 36.

---

**[1]**: here the evaluation order of function call arguments is not important, the result is the same because there are no side-effects. Some languages (like Scheme) leave the order of evaluation unspecified to prevent programmer from relying on a given order; other languages define a strict left-to-right evaluation order (e.g. Common Lisp). Here let's assume we evaluate from left-to-right.